# PHP/SQL: POST to db permutes other fields not the intended one

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a very peculiar bug here. **Classes and such are trunc'd for readability.**

SHORT DESC: Posting a value to field `nationality` changes the field from 0 to 1 and vice versa WHILE **changing** the value of the **next** field to the **first** character that was put in **by the user** in the nationality field.
If repeated (form resubmission with different input upd8ing the user entry), the first letter gets shifted to the next field while the newly put in first letter of the nationality field is the former field. THis goes three fields deep, after that there are no more "ghost changes".

## How do I stop it and get the nationality into the nationality field?

Long Description:

What I have:
I have a table 'user' in a Mysql 5.1.61 (client) and 5.5.28-log(srvr) environment.

That table used to contain, amongst others those fields:

```
{birthdate, gender, phone, mobile}
```

I added a field before gender using the qry  {`ALTER TABLE 'user' ADD 'nationality' varchar(40) AFTER 'birthdate'}` resulting in

```
{birthdate, nationality, gender, phone, mobile}
```

I feed the table with data from a form that posts these values:

```
if ($resp->is_valid) {      
    registerNewUser($_POST['email'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['firstname'], $_POST['password']);
    updateCurrentUser($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['date_of_birth'], $_POST['nationality'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['telephone'], $_POST['mobile']);
```

`updateCurrentUser` looks like this:

```
function &updateCurrentUser($email, $name, $firstname, $street, $city, $postalCode, $DateOfBirth, $nationality, $gender, , $telephone, $mobile, $hasRoomForRent, $isIaesteMember, $hasMadeTraineeship, $password, $dataApproved){

    $dbh = getPDO();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE  user  SET  name = :name, first_name = :firstname, street = :street, city = :city, postal_code = :postalCode, date_of_birth = :dateOfBirth, nationality = :nationality, gender = :gender, telephone = :telephone, mobile = :mobile, hasRoomForRent = :hasRoomForRent, isIaesteMember = :isIaesteMember, hasMadeTraineeship = :hasMadeTraineeship, dataIsApproved = :dataIsApproved '.((isset($password) && $password != 'password')? ',password = :password': '').' WHERE email = :email'); 

    $stmt->bindParam(':dateOfBirth', $DateOfBirth);

    $stmt->bindParam(':nationality', $nationality);

    $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $gender);

    $stmt->bindParam(':telephone', $telephone);

    $stmt->bindParam(':mobile', $mobile);
```

THis is the user class

```
class User {
    private $email;
    private $firstname;
    private $name;
    private $street;
    private $city;
    private $postalCode;
    private $dateOfBirth;
    private $nationality;
    private $gender;
    private $telephone;
    private $mobile;
... 
public function getNationality() {
        return $this->nationality

...;
```

I genuinely dont know what is going on. The order of the fields seems to stack up what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You specified the arguments $street, $city, $postalCode before $DateOfBirth so in your function what you may have been referencing as $DateofBirth may end up being the telephone number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your insert or update queries ensuring all parameters are inserted the way they exist in the table structure
if your table contains feilds in the order
// { birthdate,nationality,gender,phone,mobile}
then insert query should be
insert into tablename values('01-10-1991','indian','m','6667669','67686767');
also check the data types before inserting

Comment: Thank you everyone - I have found the solution and it is quite simple:
The indices of the function werent in the right order:

`function &getUserModelFromDb($email){

 $dbh = getPDO();

 $user = new User();

 if ($email == NULL){

  $email = getUserEmail();

 }

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT  <fields blabla >);

 $dataFound = false;

if ($stmt->execute(array($email))) {

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

   $dataFound = true;

   $user->setEmail($row[0]);

   $user->setName($row[1]);

   $user->setFirstname($row[2]);`